# Import from <class 'bytes'> instead of file

Tags: python, python-import

In Python I have .pyd shared library that is encrypted to .epyd and that I read and decrypt with

```py
with open('src_nuitka/src.epyd', 'rb') as f:
     my_pyd_module = decrypt(f.read())
```

Now I would like to import the module using the `<class 'bytes'>` object `my_pyd_module` directly without writing to disk first. How can I do this? Since it is not a Python code string, I cannot use `exec`. Is there an import hook available for this task? All examples of writing import hooks did this using `exec` or by instantiating the classes directly as in https://dev.to/dangerontheranger/dependency-injection-with-import-hooks-in-python-3-5hap.

---

So here is my first try using the ideas of @a_guest and https://dev.to/dangerontheranger/dependency-injection-with-import-hooks-in-python-3-5hap (and no en-/decrypting yet):

```py
import importlib.abc
import importlib.machinery
import sys

class DependencyInjectorFinder(importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder):
    def __init__(self, loader):
        self._loader: DependencyInjectorLoader = loader
    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        if fullname == 'src2':
            return importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(fullname, self._loader)

class DependencyInjectorLoader(importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader):
    def get_data(self, path):
        with open('src_packaged/src_dist/src.pyd', 'rb') as f:
            module = f.read()
        return module

sys.meta_path.append(DependencyInjectorFinder(DependencyInjectorLoader('src2', 'src2')))
import src2
```

which results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

for the last line.

Comment: Have you tried converting the bytes to a regular string? (my_pyd_module.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: @BlackBeans: What should I do then with the string? Since it is not Python code but a shared library I cannot use `exec`, as mentioned.

Comment: I'd have to look for more details, but what you look for is in the python standard library. You can search for it on the official doc site, there is a section dedicated to all kind of import hooks.

Comment: @BlackBeans: I have consulted the python standard library. It is very possible that I missed what you are refering to, but I did not find anything that I could use directly and I was not able to build what I am looking for myself. And I have really tried hard. If you a link to what you are thinking of, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: @Make42 I think it's [this function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c7b55e929b35ccab552f9efd49eed4a168e97e2f/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L1107) that is responsible for importing the module if you did `import my_pyd_module` after writing it to disk. So maybe you can build upon these steps, though it requires access to internal objects `importlib._bootstrap_external._imp`.

Comment: @a_guest: The function is essentiall calling `_imp.exec_dynamic(module)`, which sounds to me like it is calling `exec`... How would I find this `_imp.exec_dynamic`? Is this C-compiled stuff? How could I build on that?

Comment: @Make42 This function is implemented in C, I don't know exactly what it does. But you could try the following. Subclass `importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader` and override its [`get_data`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c7b55e929b35ccab552f9efd49eed4a168e97e2f/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L969) method to return `my_pyd_module`. Then install a custom [`PathFinder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.PathFinder) in `sys.meta_path` which then creates a spec that points to the custom loader inheriting from `ExtensionFileLoader`.

Comment: @a_guest: Oh snap, that might actually work! So the "custom PathFinder" would subclass `importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder`, right? That is what I gathered from https://dev.to/dangerontheranger/dependency-injection-with-import-hooks-in-python-3-5hap. Is the presented framework in https://dev.to/dangerontheranger/dependency-injection-with-import-hooks-in-python-3-5hap what you had in mind? I would copy this framework then, but instead of subclassing from `importlib.abc.Loader`, I would subclass `importlib.machinery.ExtensionFileLoader`?

Comment: @Make42 Yes something like their `DependencyInjectorFinder`. And `DependencyInjectorLoader` subclasses `ExtensionFileLoader` where the only thing you need to override is `get_data` returning `my_pyd_module`.

Comment: @a_guest: I gave it a shot, but got the error I posted in the question.

Comment: @Make42 Seems like an issue with PyCharm or one of its plugins. Can you try to run that code directly from a shell?

Comment: @a_guest: The mentioning was just, because it originated in the PyCharm Python Console. I ran the code in a terminal and changed the error message in the question accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212430/discussion-between-a-guest-and-make42).